# How to animate multiple HTML5 canvas objects one after another?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to make an animation using the HTML5 canvas and JavaScript. The idea is to write classes for different objects, like this:

```
    class Line {
      constructor(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y2;
        ...
      }

      draw() {
        }
    }

    class Circle {
      constructor(x, y, radius) {
        this.x = x;
        ...
      }

      draw() {}
    }

    ...
```

Then all you would have to do in the main code is to draw the shapes one after another with pauses in between:

```
let line1 = new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
let circle = new Circle(x, y, r);
let line2 = new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2);

line1.draw()
pause()
circle.draw()
pause()
line2.draw()

...
```

Is there an easy way to this (without  having to deal with Promises and nested Callback Functions), for example by using some library?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your setup looks solid and on the right path. It's easier for us, and eventually way better for you, if you do research on the web on your options and try one out. People here will be eager to help you once you can show that you have tried.

Comment: I would use [GSAP](https://greensock.com/)

Comment: GSAP sounds interesting, I'll will definitely give it a try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Key frames

You can use key frames to great effect to animate almost anything.

The example below (was going to do more of a write up but I was too late, you have accepted an answer) shows how a very basic key frame utility can create animations.

A key frame is just a `time` and a `value`

Key frames are added to tracks that give a name to the value.

Thus the name `x` (position) and the keys {time:0, value:100}, {time:1000, value:900} will change the `x` property from `100` to `900` during the time 0 to 1 second

For example a circle

```
const circle = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    r: 10,
    col : "",
    draw() { 
        ctx.fillStyle = this.col;
        ctx.beginPath(); 
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2); 
        ctx.fill() 
    }
};
```

can have any of its properties changed over time.

First create a tracks object and define the keys

```
const circleTracks = createTracks();

// properties to animate
circleTracks.addTrack("x");
circleTracks.addTrack("y");
circleTracks.addTrack("r");
circleTracks.addTrack("col");
```

Then add key frames at specific time stamps.

```
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(0, {x: 220, y :85, r: 20, col: "#F00"});
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(1000, {x: 220, y :50, r: 50, col: "#0F0"});
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(2000, {x: 420, y :100, r: 20, col: "#00F"});
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(3000, {x: 180, y :160, r: 10, col: "#444"});
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(4000, {x: 20, y :100, r: 20});
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(5000, {x: 220, y :85, r: 10, col: "#888"});
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(5500, {r: 10, col: "#08F"});
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(6000, {r: 340, col: "#00F"});
```

When ready clean up the the keys (You can add them out of time order)

```
circleTracks.clean();
```

Seek to the start

```
circleTracks.seek(0);
```

And update the object

```
circleTracks.update(circle);
```

To animate just call the tick and update functions, and draw the circle

```
circleTracks.tick();
circleTracks.update(circle);
circle.draw();
```

### Example

Click to start the animation.
When it ends you can scrub the animation using `tracks.seek(time)`

This is the most basic keyframe animations.

And the best thing about key frames is that they separate the animation from the code, letting you import and export animations as simple data structures.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);

const allTracks = [];
function addKeyframedObject(tracks, object) {
    tracks.clean();
    tracks.seek(0);
    tracks.update(object);
    allTracks.push({tracks, object});
}
const FRAMES_PER_SEC = 60, TICK = 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SEC; //
const key = (time, value) => ({time, value});
var playing = false;
var showScrubber = false;
var currentTime = 0;
function mainLoop() {
    ctx.clearRect(0 ,0 ,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    if(playing) {
        for (const animated of allTracks) {
            animated.tracks.tick();
            animated.tracks.update(animated.object);
        }
    }
    for (const animated of allTracks) {
        animated.object.draw();
    }

    
    if(showScrubber) {
    
        slide.update();
        slide.draw();
        if(slide.value !== currentTime) {
            currentTime = slide.value;
            for (const animated of allTracks) {
                animated.tracks.seek(currentTime);
                animated.tracks.update(animated.object);
            }
        }
        
    } else {
        if(mouse.button) { playing = true }
    }
    if(allTracks[0].tracks.time > 6300) { 
        showScrubber = true 
        playing = false;
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}





const text = {
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2,
    alpha: 1,
    text: "",
    draw() { 
        ctx.font = "24px arial";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.globalAlpha = this.alpha;
        ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    }
}
const circle = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    r: 10,
    col : "",
    draw() { 
        ctx.fillStyle = this.col;
        ctx.beginPath(); 
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2); 
        ctx.fill() 
    }
}




const circleTracks = createTracks();
circleTracks.addTrack("x");
circleTracks.addTrack("y");
circleTracks.addTrack("r");
circleTracks.addTrack("col");

circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(0, {x: 220, y :85, r: 20, col: "#F00"});
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(1000, {x: 220, y :50, r: 50, col: "#0F0"});
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(2000, {x: 420, y :100, r: 20, col: "#00F"});
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(3000, {x: 180, y :160, r: 10, col: "#444"});
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(4000, {x: 20, y :100, r: 20});
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(5000, {x: 220, y :85, r: 10, col: "#888"});
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(5500, {r: 10, col: "#08F"});
circleTracks.addKeysAtTime(6000, {r: 340, col: "#00F"});

addKeyframedObject(circleTracks, circle);


const textTracks = createTracks();
textTracks.addTrack("alpha");
textTracks.addTrack("text");
textTracks.addKeysAtTime(0, {alpha: 1, text: "Click to start"});
textTracks.addKeysAtTime(1, {alpha: 0});
textTracks.addKeysAtTime(20, {alpha: 0, text: "Simple keyframed animation"});
textTracks.addKeysAtTime(1000, {alpha: 1});
textTracks.addKeysAtTime(2000, {alpha: 0});
textTracks.addKeysAtTime(3500, {alpha: 0, text: "The END!" });
textTracks.addKeysAtTime(3500, {alpha: 1});
textTracks.addKeysAtTime(5500, {alpha: 1});
textTracks.addKeysAtTime(6000, {alpha: 0, text: "Use slider to scrub"});
textTracks.addKeysAtTime(6300, {alpha: 1});
addKeyframedObject(textTracks, text);



function createTracks() {
    return {
        tracks: {},
        addTrack(name, keys = [], value) {  
            this.tracks[name] = {name, keys, idx: -1, value}
        },
        addKeysAtTime(time, keys) {
            for(const name of Object.keys(keys)) {
                this.tracks[name].keys.push(key(time, keys[name]));
            }
        },
        clean() {
            for(const track of Object.values(this.tracks)) {
                track.keys.sort((a,b) => a.time - b.time);
            }
        },
        seek(time) { // seek to random time
            this.time = time;
            for(const track of Object.values(this.tracks)) {
                if (track.keys[0].time > time) {
                    track.idx = -1; // befor first key
                }else {
                    let idx = 1;
                    while(idx < track.keys.length) {
                        if(track.keys[idx].time > time && track.keys[idx-1].time <= time) {
                            track.idx = idx - 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        idx += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            this.tick(0);
        }, 
        tick(timeStep = TICK) { 
            const time = this.time += timeStep;
            for(const track of Object.values(this.tracks)) {
                if(track.keys[track.idx + 1] && track.keys[track.idx + 1].time <= time) {
                    track.idx += 1;
                }
                if(track.idx === -1) {
                    track.value = track.keys[0].value;
                } else {
                    const k1 = track.keys[track.idx];
                    const k2 = track.keys[track.idx + 1];
                    if (typeof k1.value !== "number" || !k2) {
                        track.value = k1.value;
                    } else if (k2) {
                        const unitTime = (time - k1.time) / (k2.time - k1.time);
                        track.value = (k2.value - k1.value) * unitTime + k1.value;
                    } 
                }
                
            }
        },
        update(obj) {
            for(const track of Object.values(this.tracks)) {
                obj[track.name] = track.value;
            }
        }   
    };
};














const slide = {
    min: 0,
    max: 6300,
    value: 6300,
    top: 160,
    left: 1,
    height: 9,
    width: 438,
    slide: 10,
    slideX: 0,
    draw() {
        
        
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.fillRect(this.left-1, this.top-1, this.width+ 2, this.height+ 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#888";
        ctx.fillRect(this.left, this.top, this.width, this.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#DDD";
        this.slideX = (this.value - this.min) / (this.max - this.min) * (this.width - this.slide)  + this.left;
        ctx.fillRect(this.slideX, this.top + 1, this.slide, this.height - 2);
    },
    
    update() {

         if(mouse.x > this.left && mouse.x < this.left + this.width && 
            mouse.y > this.top && mouse.y < this.top + this.height) {
            
            if (mouse.button && !this.captured) {
                this.captured = true;
            } else {
                canvas.style.cursor = "ew-resize";
            }
         }
         if (this.captured) {
            if (!mouse.button) {
               this.captured = false;
               canvas.style.cursor = "default";
            } else {
               this.value = ((mouse.x - this.left) / this.width) * (this.max - this.min) + this.min;
               canvas.style.cursor = "none";
               this.value = this.value < this.min ? this.min : this.value > this.max ? this.max : this.value;
               
            }
         } 
     }
 };
        
        
        
const mouse  = {x : 0, y : 0, button : false};
function mouseEvents(e){
     const bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;
    mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
}
["down","up","move"].forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse"+name,mouseEvents));
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="440" height="170"><canvas>
```

Comment: I always wanted to learn it! The secret is revealed :D Thanks to share your knowledge :D

Answer (score 1):

A good question given that what you don't want to do (use promises and/or callbacks) would effectively mean hard coding the animation in script with limited potential for re-use, and possibly creating difficulties in making modifications in the future.

A solution that I've used is to create a story book of functions that draw frames, so you would put

```
()=>line1.draw()
```

into the book rather than

```
line1.draw()
```

which would draw it immediately and try adding its return value to the book!

The next part (in no particular order) is a player that uses [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) to time stepping through the story book and calling functions to draw the frame. Minimally it would need methods for script to

- add a frame drawing function,
- add a delay before advancing to the next frame, and
- play the animation.

Making the delay function take a number of frames to wait before calling the next entry in the story book keeps it simple, but creates timings based on frame rate which may not be constant.

Here's a simplified example in pure JavaScript that changes background color (not canvas manipulation) for demonstration - have a look for reference if you can't get it working.

```js
"use strict";
class AnimePlayer {
    constructor() {
        this.storyBook = [];
        this.pause = 0;
        this.drawFrame = this.drawFrame.bind( this);
        this.frameNum = 0;
    }
    addFrame( frameDrawer) {
        this.storyBook.push( frameDrawer);
    }
    pauseFrames(n) {
        this.storyBook.push ( ()=>this.pause = n);
    }
    play() {
        this.frameNum = 0;
        this.drawFrame();
    }
    drawFrame() {
        if( this.pause > 0) {
            --this.pause;
           requestAnimationFrame( this.drawFrame);
        }
        else if( this.frameNum < this.storyBook.length) {
           this.storyBook[this.frameNum]();
           ++this.frameNum;
           requestAnimationFrame( this.drawFrame);
        }
    }
}

let player = new AnimePlayer();
let style = document.body.style;

player.addFrame( ()=> style.backgroundColor = "green");
player.pauseFrames(60);
player.addFrame( ()=> style.backgroundColor = "yellow");
player.pauseFrames(5);
player.addFrame( ()=>style.backgroundColor = "orange");
player.pauseFrames(60);
player.addFrame( ()=> style.backgroundColor = "red");
player.pauseFrames(60);
player.addFrame( ()=> style.backgroundColor = "");

function tryMe() {
    console.clear();
    player.play();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="tryMe()">try me</button>
```